# Download a file using server script and then upload it to BLOB Storage

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services, onedrive

I've got a requirement for my app that is causing some pain and I really have no idea on how to sort it out.
What I need to do is to download a file in the `insert` script of a table, upload it to the *BLOB Storage* and save the final link into the table.

The idea is to send a http request to the download link and save the file somewhere before creating the SAS to move the file to the storage.

While this sounds quite easy, it's really hard to find something online.

I've discovered [this topic](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/25c7705a-4ea0-4d9c-af09-cb48a031d06c/create-thumbnail-image-using-windows-azure-blob-storage?forum=windowsazurepurchasing) which seems to have a working solution, but my script hangs because it can't find the `memorystream` module so I wasn't able to try it at all (and I'm not sure that this is what I really need).

Following [this example](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-windows-phone-upload-data-blob-storage/) I wrote the code to generate the SAS in the *insert.js* script, which is something like

```
var azure = require('azure');
var qs = require('querystring');
var appSettings = require('mobileservice-config').appSettings;
var containerName = "unilifeblob";
var httpRequest = require('request');

function insert(item, user, request) {
    // Get storage account settings from app settings. 
    var accountName = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_NAME;
    var accountKey = appSettings.STORAGE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_KEY;
    var host = accountName + '.blob.core.windows.net';
    var sasQueryString = "";
    var oneDriveLink = item.Uri;    
    var blobService = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accountKey, host);
        blobService.createContainerIfNotExists(containerName, {
            publicAccessLevel: 'blob'
        }, function(error) {
            if (!error) {
                // Provide write access to the container for the next 5 mins.        
                var sharedAccessPolicy = {
                    AccessPolicy: {
                        Permissions: azure.Constants.BlobConstants.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
                        Expiry: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
                    }
                };
                // Generate the upload URL with SAS for the new file.
                var sasQueryUrl = blobService.generateSharedAccessSignature(containerName, item.resourceName, sharedAccessPolicy);

                // Set the query string.
                sasQueryString = qs.stringify(sasQueryUrl.queryString);
                httpRequest.get({
                    url: oneDriveLink,
                    encoding: null
                }, function (error, response, body){
                    if(error)
                        console.error(error)
                    else{
                        console.log(response + "\n" + body);
                        request.execute();
                    }
                });
                // Set the full path on the new new item, 
                // which is used for data binding on the client. 
                item.Uri = sasQueryUrl.baseUrl + sasQueryUrl.path;

            } else {
                console.error(error);
            }            
        });
    request.execute();
}
```

but this fails with this error:

> { [Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND] code: 'ENOTFOUND', errno: 'ENOTFOUND', syscall: 'getaddrinfo' }

Now, I'm sure that my script isn't well written, but I've no idea on how to go on from this.
I don't even know if I can download a file using the server script, and there's nothing useful online.

Can anybody help me?